# PHP: Complicated String With Single and Double Quotes

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass GET variables inside the URL with a bit of html inside of my PHP but can't figure out the quotes situation. I need to embed two variables inside the URL. I have one in but don't know how to embed the other. Here is the string:

```
echo "<a href='?id=".($id-1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a>";
```

and here is what I need to go inside

```
&City=$City
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its pretty simple,

```
echo "<a href='?id=".($id-1)."&city=" . $City . "' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In php double quotes `""` can eval variables inside them.

```
$test = "123;"
echo "0$test456"; // prints 0123456
```

In your case you better use single quote `''`.

```
echo '<a href=\'?id=' . ($id-1) . '&City=' . $City . '\' class=\'button\'>PREVIOUS</a>';
```

or better

```
echo '<a href="?id=' . ($id-1) . '&City=' . $City . '" class="button">PREVIOUS</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need (well, it's good practice anyway) to use `&amp;` for your ampersand. Otherwise it's fairly straight forward;

```
echo "<a href='?id=".($id-1)."&amp;City=$City' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a>";
```

This is because you are using double quotes, which means you can put variables directly into the string (there are some exceptions which you might need to put in curly brackets `{}`).

I suggest you get a text editor with syntax highlighting, such as jEdit (other editors are available).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
echo "<a href='?id=".$id."&City=".$city."'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is it better to use the sprintf function

```
$id = 100;
$previousId = $id - 1;
$City = 'Amsterdam';
$link = '<a href="?id=%1$s&City=%2$d" class="button">PREVIOUS</a>';

echo sprintf($link, $id, $City);
```